# Where is "Viewing Localizable Strings" in Xcode 4.2

Tags: iphone, xcode, localization, xcode4.2

With Interface Builder 3.0 and later you can view all of the localized strings in a table. (http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/LocalizingInterfaces.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002138-SW4)

How to do the same thing in Xcode 4.2?

Answer (score 0):

When viewing a storyboard, show the Utilities pane (the far right button in the View toggle button in the toolbar). This is the pane you usually use the Attributes inspector and Object library (where you choose objects such as UIImageViews). Instead of the Attributes, use the top left button in that pane to show the File inspector. From there you'll find the Localization panel, where you can add localizations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am looking for how to view all localized strings in XIB file using xcode 4.2 same as the Interface Builder 3.0